# SPARQL SubQuery in Filter

Tags: sparql, amazon-neptune

```
SELECT ?Name FROM <http://.../biblio.rdf>
WHERE { ?Aut name ?Name . ?Pub author ?Aut . ?Pub conf ?Conf
FILTER (?Conf IN ( SELECT ?ConfX FROM <http://.../biblio.rdf>
WHERE { ?ConfX series "ISWC" }))}
```

I have taken the query from http://www.renzoangles.net/files/amw2011.pdf.

Getting the malformed query syntax error when I tried the above format in AWS Neptune.

Please help me fix the above query.

Comment: this paper just showed some suggestion how subqueries could be added to SPARQL 1.0 standard, but the one with the FILTER never made it to SPARQL 1.1

Comment: the obvious solution is to use a good old join: `SELECT ?Name FROM <http://.../biblio.rdf>
WHERE { ?Aut name ?Name . ?Pub author ?Aut . ?Pub conf ?Conf .
?Conf series "ISWC" }`

Comment: that said, the predicates like `name`, `author`, etc. are indeed also invalid identifiers, given that the paper just showed pseudo syntax. You have to use a prefixed or full URI of those predicates

Comment: last but not least, I doubt there is any guarantee that the `FROM <http://.../biblio.rdf>` will work - imagine, this loads an arbitrary file into the triple store, who wants to allow this? It can, but I'm sure many won't (out of the box)

Comment: @UninformedUser I didn't use the exact query But tried other query with sub query in filter. Seems like this thing is not in 1.1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test that a triple is in the data, which seems to be the intention of the exampel of "FILTER IN SELECT " here, yuo can use `FILTER EXISTS`

```
FILTER EXISTS { ?Conf series "ISWC" }
```

Comment: Agree, But my intention is not to check the existence of the triplet. I am experimenting with the subquery in flter.

Comment: `EXISTS` is a form of subquery. It's like an `ASK` subquery.